# The type Facebook.FacebookClient is defined in an assembly that is not referenced

Tags: c#, .net, facebook-c#-sdk

I have downloaded the latest FaceBook C# SDK and have added the FaceBook.Web.dll (net40) to my project which is also .net v4.0.

When I copied the following code from the [example page](http://facebooksdk.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Code%20Examples&referringTitle=Documentation):

```
var client2 = new FacebookClient();
var me2 = (IDictionary<string, object>)client2.Get("me");
string firstName = (string)me2["first_name"];
string lastName = (string)me2["last_name"];
string email = (string)me2["email"];
```

I get this error:

> The type or namespace name 'FacebookClient' does not exist in the
>   namespace 'Facebook.Web' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

So I changed:

```
var client2 = new Facebook.Web.FacebookClient();
```

to

```
var client2 = new Facebook.Web.FacebookWebClient();
```

Now I have two errors:

> The type 'Facebook.FacebookClient' is defined in an assembly that is
>   not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'Facebook,
>   Version=5.4.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=58cb4f2111d1e6de'.

and

> 'Facebook.Web.FacebookWebClient' does not contain a definition for
>   'Get' and no extension method 'Get' accepting a first argument of type
>   'Facebook.Web.FacebookWebClient' could be found (are you missing a
>   using directive or an assembly reference?)

Before I added the FaceBook C# SDK, I upgraded my project from v3.5 to v4.0 of .NET. I was able to successfully build and run my application.

I then added the Facebook dll and could not get it working.
(I have tried both the v3.5 and v4.0 version of the Facebook dll).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The messages try to tell you that you also need to add a reference to the Facebook.dll in the project that already references Facebook.Web.dll

Comment: Oh, can't believe I missed this. I had the Facebook.Web dll added as a reference but not the Facebook.dll one! Just to clarify, the Facebook.Web.dll is in the \net40\ folder and the Facebook.dll is in the \net40-client\ folder. Do I need both of them yes?

Answer (score 0):

have you added a `using facebook` statement in your code?

also unless it is within a method, I dont beleive you are allowed to use `var` keyword as a global field init

Comment: It is inside a method. The code has both using Facebook; and using Facebook.Web;

Answer (score 0):

Try to change Specific Version of Facebook.dll to "false".

Answer (score 0):

I encountered same problem.There seems to be an assembly conflict between facebook c# sdk and facebook.helper libraries.I Uninstalled facebook.helper {version} and it worked.